# showing DateTime in simple format?

Tags: asp.net

i have a column in my database that stores DateTime, now i want to show time in simple format,
you know it will appear like : `12/26/2011 9:39:55 PM`

but i want to show it in persian.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to format the `DateTime` in your application, you need to use a `DateTime.ToString` overload.

Select the appropriate [standard Date and Time format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) - in this case `"g"` looks like a good fit.

If you have not [set up your webserver to use the `fa-IR` culture by default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx), you will need to pass this culture in as well.

```
string farsiDate = myDateTime.ToString("g", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fa-IR");
```

Comment: it returned 12/26/2011 05:33 ب.ظ  this is not Farsi Date :(

Comment: @AProgrammer - It is a date formatted according to the Farsi culture. What would a Farsi date look like?

Comment: For example 21/03/1390  21 : Day , 03 : Month , 1390 : Year

Comment: @AProgrammer - You are talking about something like the Hajiri calendar. That's a different thing.

Comment: @AProgrammer - See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601725/hijri-and-gregorian-datetime-constructor).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the examples on MSDN for using the [PersianCalendar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.persiancalendar.aspx) class.

```
var cal = new PersianCalendar();

var today = DateTime.Now;

var persianDate = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", 
    cal.GetDayOfMonth(today), 
    cal.GetMonth(today), 
    cal.GetYear(today));
```