# Sql query to get the arabic date for the gregorian date from a database

Tags: c#, sql-server, gregorian-calendar, hijri

I have a table with columns Hijri date and Gregorian date. I want a select query to fetch the Hijri date from this table by passing the Gregorian date. I will pass the Gregorian date as a parameter from my code in C#.

Comment: Do you mean Gregorian date? It's not clear how the Gregorian date relates to the Hijri date here.

Comment: A 'Gorgon date' sounds intriguing...

Comment: any reason you don't use the .NET built-in classes for Hijjri dates to make the conversion ?

Answer (score 0):

SqlServer can convert Gregorian date into Hijri by using the `CONVERT` function and supplying the appropriate style 130 or 131. See also [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Assuming you have stored your dates in Gregorian calendar in your database you can use this to get the Hijri date:

```
DateTime start = ...
DateTime end = ...

...

var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CONVERT(varchar, YourDateColumn, 131) FROM YourTable WHERE YourDateColumn BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdate", start);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddate", end);
```

If you want something else you need to be more specific.

The answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601725/hijri-and-gregorian-datetime-constructor) shows some examples of how to perform datetime convertions with Hijri in .NET.