# Hijri dates with DefaultView RowFilter

Tags: c#, datetime, hijri

I am working with data table and using hijri dates when trying to filter dates like so:

```
 dayDutyTableFilter.DefaultView.RowFilter = "EmployeeID = '" + pRow["PersonID"].ToString() + "' And DayDutyDate >= '" + firstDayMonth
                    + "' And  DayDutyDate <= '" + lastDayMonth + "'";
```

I got the following error:

> Specified time is not supported in this calendar. It should be between
>   04/30/1900 00:00:00 (Gregorian date) and 11/16/2077 23:59:59
>   (Gregorian date), inclusive.

Comment: What are the values of `firstDayMonth` and `lastDayMonth` _exactly_? Are they `DateTime`'s?

Comment: yes datetimes but they are hijri datetimes like 06/01/1435 12:00:00 ص

Comment: How did you create your `DateTime`'s exactly? Can you please show their definitions as well?

Comment: they are stored in database ,when they are pulled to my application they become hijri because the current thread culture is hijri

Answer (score 0):

> they are stored in database ,when they are pulled to my application
>   they become hijri because the current thread culture is hijri

#### No.

A culture has *no* effect to `Calender` of a `DateTime` value. Without any `Calender` definition in your `DateTime` constructor, a `DateTime` is always *Gregorian Calender* by default.

Looks like your `06/01/1435 12:00:00` value is *still* in Gregorian Calender which is not between your values.

If you use SQL Server for example, all [Date and Time Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848733.aspx) save your value with Gregorian Calender.

Comment: @husseinshaib My suggestion is; you can convert your Gregorian calender to Hijri Calender and use this `DateTime`. Read http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/M.%20Kaisoun/convert-date-from-solar-gregorian-to-lunar-hijri-using-c153/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189807/cannot-convert-from-hijri-date-to-gregorian-date-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601725/hijri-and-gregorian-datetime-constructor and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075759/convert-between-calendars

Comment: Thx I have come arround this problem and changed the way i was filtering data

Comment: @husseinshaib Great. Making a standard of when you get values and when you save them is always a good idea.